# Using functions in react native render

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 2 functions called `isTrue` and `isFalse`.

```
export function isTrue(param) {
  return param === true;
};

export function isFalse(param) {
  return param === false;
};
```

I have a few buttons in react native which change from disabled state want a variable is true or false. I could do it like this:

```
<Button
  text="This is a button"
  onPress={handlePress}
  isDisabled={var === true}
/>
```

But now I'm using the functions like this:

```
<Button
  text="This is a button"
  onPress={handlePress}
  isDisabled={isTrue(var)}
/>
```

When adding a console.log to the 'isTrue'-function, I see it gets called a lot (every re-render).

Is this bad for performance. I'm not seeing any performance issues, but it's quiet a simple app (for now) and I don't think the calculations in this function is't difficult.

I'm planning to add more functions like `isNull`, `isNotNull`. It's just for myself, `var === null` works like `isNull(var)` but for me it's easier to read. If there could be any performance issues, I switch back again.

Comment: It's fine. It's just how react works, you can't do anything about it and it's not a performance issue

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. It's just how react works, you can't do anything about it and it's not a performance issue

But these particular functions don't do anything, you could just do

```
<Button
  text="This is a button"
  onPress={handlePress}
  isDisabled={var}
/>
```

If something is `true` or `false`, you don't have to additionally compare them to `true` or `false`

```js
const x = true
console.log(x, x === true)
```